# How to upload a local file during test execution on AWS Device Farm (desktop)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, aws-device-farm, selenium-remotedriver

I have a portion of a website that I'm testing that accepts uploading of image files. The DOM element is a standard `input type=file`. There are zero issues with test execution locally.

The test fails in AWS Device farm, I'm assuming because even though the code during execution finds the image file successfully (because execution is taking place on a local machine), the call to attach/upload the file remotely to AWS isn't possible.

Is it possible to mount paths to AWS Device Farm (similar to how it is done in Docker)? Or are there other methods of file upload to Device Farm that I can follow?

Comment: I did not. I gave up a while ago. I think it might be possible to try to upload an image from a remote resource and send that to the input in the DOM. But I am really not sure.